# How to make nginx CORS configuration(add_header) work?

Tags: nginx, header, cors, addition

The nginx(v1.14) is reverse proxy server, it sends api request to tomcat. I add some CORS configurations in the conf file but it doesn't work. Nginx conf file is as following:

```
upstream tomcat_server1 {
    server 172.20.10.2:8080;
}


server {
        listen 80;

        root /opt/nginx/www;

        server_name 172.20.10.2;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat_server1;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://172.20.10.2:8080';
        }

        location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|ico|html)$ {
            root /opt/nginx/www/;
        }
}
```

It seems that the add_header directive doesn't work, the browser console shows information like this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://172.20.10.2:8080/user/login?email=81438234%40qq.com&password=236e3402dbab51ea17f9f6f360993233. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The response header is like this:
[image]

I don't know how to get it works.

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Nginx Doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header), add_header will only take effect when the response code equals to "200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0)".

By having no knowledge of this fact, I just struggled for hours for the 400 response code... and finally resolved with assigning "**always**" flag like:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://172.20.10.2' always;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this one

```
location / {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://172.20.10.2';
            proxy_pass 172.20.10.2:8080;
        }
```

Comment: if I remove http prefix of proxy_pass, the server can't start, the log shows that:invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:30.   So I add the http prefix to 172.20.10.2:8080, but it still doesn't work